# Console log is return 'undefined' for $index. Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All.

I written this sort of code before and now I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This snippet of code is running when the menu buttons are clicked.

```
$scope.show = function($index){
    console.log($index);
  };
```

The console log is returning 'undefined'.

Can any one help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Js bin below:
https://jsbin.com/keteji/edit?html,js,console,output

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks, All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `$index` is an iterator offset of the repeated element which is exposed on the local scope of each template instance in [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

As you have `dataArray` as menu-list, Use `ng-repeat` to get `iterations` in the `view`

Try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('angularApp',[]);

app.controller('AppController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.dataJson = dataArray;
//   console.log($scope);
  
  
  $scope.show = function($index){
    alert($index);
  };
  
  
  $('.nav li').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  
}]);

var dataArray =[
  {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Home",
    "visible":true
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Profile",
    "visible":false
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "name":"Messages",
    "visible":false
  }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="angularApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" ng-repeat="d in dataJson" ng-click="show($index)"><a href>{{d.name}}</a></li>
      
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
      
      <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="pages in dataJson">
        <h3 ng-show="pages.visible">
          {{pages.name}}
        </h3>
      </div>  
      
      
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, so much you nailed it with the example.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`$index` is a property of `ngRepeat` Scope.

You can't find it on controllers scope.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Still getting the hang of Angular.